# Customized init method on an object to initWithWindowNibName an NSWindowController property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

What I'm trying to do is create a method to an object which opens a window.
In this window I want to output some properties of the object's instance.
To do this I created a "Profile" subclass of NSObject, which has an NSWindowController property called "view".

```
@interface Profile : NSObject {
    \\...
}

@property (readwrite, assign) NSWindowController *view;
```

Since I cannot connect "view" to the window with Interface Builder (or at least I don't know how) I have to do so with the "initWithWindowNibName". So I tried overriding the "Profile"'s init method like this:

```
-(Profile *)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        [[self view] initWithWindowNibName:@"Profile"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I don't know whether my approach is correct, fact is when I try showing the window it doesn't appear. Here's how I tried:

```
Profile *profile = [[Profile alloc] init];
[[profile view] showWindow:self];
```

Hope you can help :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling alloc on this: [[self view] initWithWindowNibName:@"Profile"];
 like this: [[[self view] alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Profile"]; ?

Comment: No, it says that the "alloc" method returns a new instance of a recieving class. In fact it gives me error when I try with that alternative :(

Comment: @mark `[[[self view] alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Profile"]` is not working because you are calling a class method `alloc` on an instance.  If you wanted to do it this way (I'm not recommending...) you would write `[[[[self view] class] alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Profile"]`

Comment: Ah, of course. Brain hick-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want something like:

```
@interface Profile:NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSWindowController *windowController;

@end
```

and:

```
- (Profile *)init {
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) { return nil; }

    self.windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Profile"];
    return self;
}
```

and:

```
// show window
Profile *profile = [[Profile alloc] init];
[[profile windowController] showWindow:self];
```

(I'm assuming ARC.)

**EDIT:**
For clarity to the OP, I followed the his property nomenclature, which was to name the `NSWindowController` property `view`.  It is confusing, though because a `NSWindowController` is not a view.  For clarity to others, I've changed it.

Comment: Rename view to windowController in your answer, it's too misleading.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer:  for clarity to the OP, I was merely following his convention.  However, I  agree with you; it's an odd choice of property name.

Comment: Yes it was a bad temporary solution, I'm going to rename it.. Anyways the answer solved exactly what I was trying to do, only didn't know how to thanks :)